# Recognizing text and Mathematica special characters when copying expressions from a PDF

Tags: notebooks, ocr

I could not find something relevant.
Last days I am reading  [Leonid Shifrin's masterpiece](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/) but I cannot copy-paste either from the pdf or from the electronic version.
Consider the function `myTiming` of page 63.

[image]

When I copy-paste from the pdf I take

```
Clear@myTimingD;
myTiming@x_D := Module@8z = 0, y = 0, timelim = 0.1,
p, q, iterlist = HPower@10, ðD &  Range@0, 10DL,
nm =
If@ToExpression@StringTake@$Version, 1DD < 6, 2, 1
D<,
Catch@
If@Hz = Nest@
First, Timing@Hy ++; Do@x, 8ð<DL;D, nmDL > timelim,
Throw@8z, y<
D
D &  iterlistD . 8p_, q_< ¦ p  iterlist@@qDD
D;
Attributes@myTimingD = 8HoldAll<;
```

I can apply the modiffications manually, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient workaround.

[The online version cannot be copied at all (it is an image)](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node297.html).
[image]

Comment: I could not find a suitable keyword.

Comment: I am afraid that this question is off-topic here, at least if it only concerns specifically my book. The result of copy-paste really depends on pdf browser, but I agree that in many it is unsatisfactory. At the time I was creating the pdf, I was on Windows and checked there, where situation seemed better. I will try to find a moment to look for the code of the book in .nb form, and make it public. The particular function in question has modern, much better and more succinct successors, such as `timeit` function of Mr.Wizard, etc. You may search for the latter on this site.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much for your answer (and I appologize for the delayed reply).